# How best to distribute a file made with FreeCAD that uses a macro

Tags: file-formats, freecad

I made a model in FreeCAD that uses a macro that I wish to distribute (with the original file, not just the STL.

A couple of closely related questions:

- If I provide only the .FCStd file, will people without that macro installed still be able to use and modify it?
- If not, is there a good way to provide this model to include all its dependencies, or am I limited to advising what macro is required?